Mysterious bulges in ceiling
My home was built in 2016. We just started to notice these two strange bulges in the ceiling. They are solid, dense sounding when tapped on compared to surrounding area. No staining and not squishy or soft. What could this be?

What is directly above these ceiling locations?  Without any other information, my first guess is that there's a water leak that's causing the drywall ceiling to sag in those two locations, but it hasn't been enough moisture (yet) to stain through the ceiling paint so far.

use small nail and try to push it in BY HAND , to test how soft is it

Dense sounding? Unfortunately, might have water in that area.  That's not normal.

I would almost say badly sagging drywall nails, but to my knowledge modern homes use drywall screws, I think it also might be water.

Could be sagging drywall, but no water stains.  My guess would be the drywall guy or a PO made a booboo there that required patching, and the glob of mud had to be feathered out quite a ways.
